# Can I use use transactions at the job level in SQL Server to reverse what a package does for testing purposes?

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2016

I'm aware that rolling back when a package fails is a thing, but in this case I want the package to roll back even if it's successful. So we can freely run packages in our testing environment without mucking up the database itself too much.

I was hoping that you could do this at the job level, something like

- Step 1: T-SQL script ("Begin Transaction;")
- Step 2: Run package
- Step 3: T-SQL Script ("Rollback Transaction;")

(With the potential addition of more packages and additional steps to output things and make sure all your steps worked correctly before they got rolled back)

Does this work on SQL Server 2016? Or can you not nest a transaction at the job scheduling level in this manner.

Other option I've seen is to do it all in a single T-SQL script, because you can call packages within one. At the very least I'm hoping to find something that doesn't involve us having to put the transaction block in at the package level and then take it out when we move it to dev.

Comment: No you can't wrap an entire SSIS package in a transaction like that. It uses different connections inside that don't form part of your job steps connection. I suggest that you use backup/restore instead. Either an explicit backup/restore or point in time restore

Comment: Bugger. Well, guess I'll have to find out how much time+space doing backup/restores is gonna take.

Comment: If you use a full recovery model, you don't need to do an explicit backup/restore. you can just restore to a point in time.